# comando linux - bloquear rename/renomear de pasta

Tags: linux, ftp, ssh, shell-script

preciso dar acesso a um usuario ftp na pasta /var/www
mas lá existe pastas que ele não pode acessar/editar/excluir

tentei um comando:

```
#chmod 000 <pasta>
```

quase deu certo, ele nao exclui, nao acessa, porém ele pode fazer rename na pasta, será que tem um jeito dele não fazer o rename ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem um procedimento que pode solucionar o seu problema

```
chmod 000 chattr +i -R
```

com o chattr +i esse código nem o root pode efetuar alterações na pasta e nos atributes dele. O -R é para tornar recursivo.

para desfazer é o código a seguir

```
chattr -i -R
```

alguns link legais:

[5 chattr uteis](http://www.tecmint.com/chattr-command-examples/)

[Outras explicações](http://www.mnxsolutions.com/amusings/amusing-a-sysadmin.html)

Answer (score 0):

Se ele for o dono da pasta ele sempre vai poder renomea-la, pois tambem vai sempre poder trocar as permissões da pasta. Sugiro que tu mude o dono da pasta para outro usuário e coloque as permissões que tu quiser em um grupo. Certifique-se de que o usuário que você quer dar as permissões pertença a este mesmo grupo.

Comment: o dono da pasta é root
dou um ls -lha p/ você entender  
`codigo` d---------  2 root root 4.0K Apr 10 09:48 zzz

mesmo o dono sendo root e mesmo o usuario nao fazendo parte de grupo nenhum ele consegue renomear a pasta